# dataTables PDF sorted table images and excel image url

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Im trying to show images of each data from a table to pdf. The image are shown but the problem is, when user sort the DataTable using the table headers in the user interface, the sorting is applied to the displayed rows, but images in the PDF export is not sorted or being updated to match the new order. Also, i tried making the images shown as url in excel but it doesnt work. How do i fix this?

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="table-report" width="100%" style="white-space: nowrap;">
              <thead align="center">
                <th>table header</th>
                <-- other table headers -->
                <th>table header</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody align="center">
                <?php
                $year1 = $_POST['year1'];
                $year2 = $_POST['year2'];
                $data = query("SELECT * FROM report WHERE YEAR(date) BETWEEN '$year1' AND '$year2' ORDER BY date DESC");
                $imageSources = array();
 
                foreach ($data as $d) :
                  $imagePath = '../uploads/' . $d['photo'];
                  $type = pathinfo($imagePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                  $imageData  = file_get_contents($imagePath);
                  $imgData = base64_encode($imageData );
                  $src = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,'.$imgData;
                  $imageSources[] = $src;
                ?>
                      <tr>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td>
                          <img src="<?= $imagePath; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
                          </td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr']; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr'] ? $d['atr'] : 'text'; ?></td>
                          <td><?= $d['atr'] ? $d['atr'] : 'text'; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                  <?php
                  endforeach;
                  ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
 
 
<?php
include "templates/footer.php";
<script>
 
 
var imageSources = <?php echo json_encode($imageSources); ?>;
var imagePath = <?php echo json_encode($imagePath); ?>;
 
$('#table-report').DataTable({
    dom: '<"datatable-buttons"B>ltip',
    lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
    order: [[1, 'desc']],
    buttons: [
        'colvis',
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                orthogonal: 'export',
            },
            customize: function(xlsx) {
                    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                    $('row c[r^="H"]', sheet).each(function(index) {
                        var imageIndex = $(this).index() - 7; // Calculate the image index based on column position
                        var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index() - 2; // Adjust the row index based on header and Excel's 1-indexing
                        var imgData = imageSources[rowIndex] || ''; // Get the image URL
                        var url = imgData ? (imagePath + imgData) : ''; // Construct the URL using $imagePath and imgData
                        $(this).find('is t').text(url); // Set the URL as the cell value
                        $(this).attr('s', '2'); // Set style to display as a URL
                    });
                }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'legal',
            exportOptions: {
              columns: ':visible'
            },
            customize: function(doc) {
              doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 10;
              doc.pageMargins = [40, 40, 40, 40];
              var arr2 = imageSources.map(function(imageSource) {
                    return imageSource;
                });
 
              for (var i = 0, c = 1; i < arr2.length; i++, c++) {
                                doc.content[1].table.body[c][7] = {
                                  image: arr2[i],
                                  width: 100
                                }
                                  }
            },
          stripHtml: true
        },
      ],
    scrollX: true,
        // fixedHeader: true,
    });
 
</script>
```